# mousedown event not working for left click

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, click, mousedown

```
  $("#cell1").mousedown(function(event){
    switch (event.which) {
    case 1:
        alert('Left Mouse button pressed.');
        break;
    case 2:
        alert('Middle Mouse button pressed.');
        break;
    case 3:
        alert('Right Mouse button pressed.');
        break;
    default:
        alert('You have a strange Mouse!');
}
```

This code runs perfectly on safari, firefox, yet on chrome, it only works for case 3 (Right Mouse  button pressed) How can this be possible? It works on every other browser, except the one that most of America uses.

Answer (score 0):

If you copy pasted your code fully, then it has issue. Try below

```js
 $("#cell1").mousedown(function(event){
            switch (event.which) {
                case 1:
                    alert('Left Mouse button pressed.');
                    break;
                case 2:
                    alert('Middle Mouse button pressed.');
                    break;
                case 3:
                    alert('Right Mouse button pressed.');
                    break;
                default:
                    alert('You have a strange Mouse!');
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="cell1" data-effect="mfp-zoom-in">test</button>
```

if the issue still persist, check in console for any error